# What is the difference between aria-owns and aria-controls

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

What is the real impact on an element when using

```
aria-owns="id"
```

and(!)

```
aria-controls="id"
```

How do the browsers notify the screen readers when these two attributes are used?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Both `aria-controls` and `aria-owns` are used when the relation between the two element can't be determined from the DOM hierarchy itself.

`aria-controls` is intended to indicate that an element controls another one. *E.g. control buttons for a video for instance, a toolbar for a visual editor or a button for a collapsible element.* Screen readers like jaws will announce a shortcut to move the visual focus to the element. This requires the element to be in the visual flow (no `display:none`).

`aria-owns` indicate that an element depends on the current one when the relation can't be determined by the hierarchy structure.

**To sum up, with an example,** if you have a carousel with three parts:

- on the left the clickable title list of each element in the carousel,
- on the right the wrapper for the slides
- on the bottom, the next and the previous buttons.

Result:

1. `aria-controls` will be applied to buttons like "*previous*" or "*next*" to point to the wrapper.
2. `aria-owns` will be applied to each element of the title list to point to each element inside the wrapper.
3. the active element in the title list would have the `aria-selected` attribute

The intended effect is that you could move the visual focus of your screenreader to the determined element.

Comment: "This seems to have no effect on screenreaders" re: `aria-owns`. This is wrong. I built a combobox component that relied on `aria-owns` for the screenreader to correctly read the highlighted options in the listbox. The screenreader did not work correctly without it.

Comment: @ericgio Thanks for your feedback. Screenreaders have made great improvements since 2015

Answer (score 16):

> The difference between -owns and -controls is that -owns creates a parent/child relationship where none exists, and -controls indicates that one thing controls the other.
>   So A can control B, but A doesn't have to be a parent of B for that to be the case.

[leonie watson](https://gitter.im/w3c/a11ySlackers?at=5655eb8a63bfb30b58e46529)

Answer (score 4):

We've found this to be especially important in 2020, as browsers and screen readers are increasing their support for aria-owns and breaking the user experience. Please check your code for aria-owns and make sure you didn't mean aria-controls.