# Can't tab into Popper from material UI split button demo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm following the demo of the [split button here](https://mui.com/components/button-group/#split-button) But it looks like the demo itself isn't accessible (you can't tab from the button to the popper).

Here's what the components looks like:

[image: screenshot of the material UI demo page for split buttons]

I've tried swapping/adding `aria-controls` for `aria-owns` (which seemed correct based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34015524/1075247)) but it's still not letting me move between the button and popper with a keyboard only.

How can I make this accessible? I'm presuming theres a good reason the demo doesn't `Menu` (from a brief look, I don't think it's as easy to position perhaps?)

Comment: Just tried it out and I managed to tab into the popper from the button. Could you please record a small gif to show us what you mean?

Comment: @ramesh I can give it a go, but I don't have any screen recording set up on a laptop - so it could be a long while before I figure that out. What did you do differently to me?

Comment: I tried both firefox and chrome. I could tab to '"squash" and the down triangle as two separate tab stops. Pressing space/enter on the triangle opened the dropdown list and the next tab moved the focus into the dropdown list. I could then arrow up/down within the list to select an option.